# does @Capturing work for lambdas?

Tags: java, java-8, jmockit

The test below seems to suggest that `@Capturing` does not work with lambdas. That is, the `lambda` test below fails while the `anonymousClass` test passes:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class CapturingTest {

    public interface Foo {
        int get();
    }

    @Test
    public void lambda(@Capturing final Foo unused) {

        // this test fails.
        // an UnsupportedOperationException is thrown

        final Foo foo = () -> {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        };
        assertThat(foo.get(), equalTo(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void anonymousClass(@Capturing final Foo unused) {
        final Foo foo = new Foo() {
            @Override
            public int get() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
        assertThat(foo.get(), equalTo(0));
    }

}
```

JMockit v1.17

Comment: Isn't it working as intended? I mean you are calling `foo.get()` which should throw an exception and it's actually doing it

Comment: @over9k [the semantics](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#capturing) of `@Capturing` specify that any derivation of the type with the annotation will be mocked - the lambda being a derivation of the `Foo` type in the example, should be mocked as well.